# searching in listbox separated with comma

Tags: c#, listbox

Hello please i have an list of items in listbox like that 
Landen, Lucie, 812-692-5576, Jig Is Up
i need to search with name or phone or Ratios .....
i have typed this code but he search with string att any place in the line

```
        int x = 0;

        string match = textBox1.Text;

        if (textBox1.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            bool found = true;
            while (found)
            {
                if (listBox1.Items.Count == x)
                {
                    listBox1.SetSelected(lastMatch, true);
                    found = false;
                    textBox2.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    listBox1.SetSelected(x, true);
                    match = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    if (match.Contains(textBox1.Text))
                    {
                        lastMatch = x;
                        found = false;
                    }
                    x++;
                    textBox2.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                }
            }
```

thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Create a class to hold your info.

```
public class Card
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", Name, Phone, Note);
    }
}
```

Create instances of it as needed.

```
var card = new Card { Name = "Landen, Lucie", Phone = "812-692-5576", Note = "Jig Is Up" };
```

Use that class to populate your `ListBox`.

```
var allTheCards = new List<Card>();
// populate the cards

listBox1.DataSource = allTheCards;
```

Now you can search particular fields. You'll have to make other updates in your code to accommodate using your own class instead of just a string.

```
Card match = listBox1.SelectedItem;

if (match.Name.Contains(textBox1.Text)
    || match.Phone.Contains(textBox1.Text)
    || match.Note.Contains(textBox1.Text))
{
    ...
}
```

---

Expanding on your comment and on what TaW suggested, you could still use this solution when reading from a file. Just loop through the results and populate your `Card` class using the results.

Here's one possible way to do it, using LINQ:

```
listBox1.DataSource = (from lines in File.ReadAllLines("someFile.txt")
                       let parts = lines.Split(',')
                       select new Card
                                  {
                                      Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", parts[1], parts[0]),
                                      Phone = parts[2],
                                      Note = parts[3]
                                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: thank so much but i load my listbox from an text file

Comment: You can load the class instances from that text file's lines by spiltting them at ','. Simply add a constructor that does that : `public Card(string input){var p=input.Split(','); Name =p[0]; Phone=p[1]; Note=p[2];}`

Answer (score 0):

What I read from your code is, you need a logic to search `List` contents and highlight first matching list item and update `TextBox` value with the SelectedListItem.

This snippet does what I explained.

```
 for(int i=0;i<listBox1.Items.Count;++i)
 {
     if(listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains("searchString"))
     {
           // match 
           listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
           textBox2.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();               
     }  
 }
```

Comment: `listBox1.SelectedItem` will be null at the time of execution of `  textBox2.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` because you are assigning selectedItem after that line

Comment: @un-lucky thanks for highlighting this, I should do the selection first. Updated now.

Comment: Great..! now its fine answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through foreach as like the following:

```
bool itemFound = false;     
object currentObject = null;  // remains null if no match found   
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    if (item.ToString().Contains(txtbox1.Text))
    {
        currentObject = item; // will give you the current item   
        textBox2.Text=item.ToString();                
        break; // Break; if you need to check for the first occurance
    }
}
if (currentObject != null)
   listBox1.SelectedItem = currentObject;
else
   textBox2.Text = "Item not found";
```